# How to receive data from jsp as GET Call

Tags: java, jsp, http-get

I have 2 jsp pages.
I am sending data from 1 jsp to another as GET request.
Now I want to display output data in the 2nd jsp but I am not able to do it.

here is my 1st jsp i.e index.jsp

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : Spago
    Created on : 14 Oct, 2016, 2:06:12 PM
    Author     : ndoshi
--%>

<%@page import="java.io.InputStreamReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
<%@page import="java.net.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.location = "http://localhost:8080/demo/index.jsp";
            }, 60000); // <-- this is the delay in milliseconds
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            try {
                String machine = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();
                String user="Niket";
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/demo/db.jsp?machine=" + machine+"&user="+user);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response1 = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response1.append(inputLine);
                }

                System.out.println(inputLine);

                out.println("Index : "+inputLine);
                in.close();

                if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my 2nd jsp i.e db.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : db.jsp
    Created on : 20 Oct, 2016, 1:29:47 PM
    Author     : ndoshi
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            out.println("Response : "+request.getParameter("machine")+","+request.getParameter("user"));
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: print exception in first jsp it could help `catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}`

Comment: I have appended, but there is no error thrown

Comment: I've tried your code this is the exception I got `java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected: connect` and why are you doing it this way?

Comment: when you say `Now I want to display output data in the 2nd jsp but I am not able to do it` you mean that your 1st jsp is rendering the second jsp inside properly but without data , or it is not rendering at all ? also could you post the exact url to get the 1st jsp page , because i dont think that `http://localhost:8080/demo/index.jsp` is valid. Also you are setting the `conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");` but you are requesting a `"text/html"`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried with json data also but it is not arriving also the url is right as I am getting output as null so I am not able to receive the data send by db.jsp & when I run db.jsp individually, I am getting the data.

Comment: I wont to pass username & machine name credentials to another jsp which will have database connection and it will check for details of user, and return the login time for the same from database.So I tried with this snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the following code with new one.

Old code :

```
String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response1 = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response1.append(inputLine);
                }

                System.out.println(inputLine);
```

New Code

```
String inputLine;
String Line="";
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Line+=inputLine;
}
out.println(Line);
```

StringBuffer does not work in this case.